# Is there a Blockchain Refund Department

Tags: blockchain

I was scammed 3 years ago by FXTrade, i know for sure that they invested my money into BTC.
About 6 months ago i recieved an email from a lawfirm that told me i had BTC to recover under my name in Blockchain, and i should be contacted by an Blockchain agent soon.
I was contacted by an agent 2 months ago, he showed me my account and there was my lost BTC in this Blockchain wallet. The agent now saying that i had to pay an upfront fee of 15% of the amount, but he was willing to reduce this payment to half of the amount and take the rest from my refund. Is there anyone that's had the same experience and do you believe this is just another scam attempt?

Comment: It's a scam. If they had your money, why would you need to send them anything? They could just reduce the amount they give you by their fee.

Comment: Scam! The only reason to send a little amount to their bitcoin address would be the hope they spend the coins together with other BTC addresses so that tracing of the scammers could be possible.